# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS networking

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all , i have a question on something that i cant figure out
I am trying to build a network between my robot's machine which is a raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 server ros noetic and a virtual machine on my laptop (VM ware) , i connected them using ROS_MASTER_URI  and ROS IP, i ran listener talker node and it works find the Raspberry Pi send a talker and the VM ware listens to it . However when i try to run turtle sim to control it from the PI the turtle doesn't move when i use the teleop for the turtle , i feel like big data cant be send or something any ideas ?

Update: when i tried to ssh both machines i can see the VM ware able to see and ping the pi but the pi can't ping the VM ware .

PS: I need this to control the robot's from my VM without connecting the pi to anything

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401470/ros-networking/) by [Os7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106188/os7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2022-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2022-05-27**:
See what `rqt_graph` is showing. Are the nodes connected to each other over the topics?
If not, I would try using not a VM but a normal PC with ubuntu on it. No VMs.

**Comment by [Os7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106188/os7/) on 2022-05-28**:
The nodes are connected yes , i even opened ros topic list and everything is showing when i echoed into the turtle cmd from the VM it shows when i change the values but the turtle don't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So changing the VM ware network from NAT to bridged solved the problem

---

Originally posted by [Os7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106188/os7/) with karma: 50 on 2022-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0